# Floating div cant center or right align

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a floating red bubble, much like used in googles material design.

I am using Materializecss for web development. Info can be found here on the floating red bubble I am trying to implement:

http://materializecss.com/buttons.html

I have tried all their built in helpers for css to move it center at the bottom but no luck. Here is my html:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Starter Template - Materialize</title>

    <!-- CSS  -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">
</head>

<body style="position: relative;">
    <div class="navbar-fixed ">

        <nav class="orange " role="navigation">
            <div id="replaceBar" class="nav-wrapper container">
                <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Beer Portfolio</a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down left">
                    <li><a href="stats.html">Statistics</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul style="left: -250px;" id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav left">
                    <li><a href="stats.html">Statistics</a></li>
                </ul>

                <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="img/menuIcon.png" height="30" width="30"></a>

                <ul id="search" class="right valign-wrapper">
                    <li class="valign">
                        <a href="#"> <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="img/searchIcon.png" height="30" width="30"></a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>


    </div>


    <div class="collection"><a href="#!" class="collection-item" id="Bitter"><h5 class="orange-text text-darken-2"> Bitter</h5> <div class="right">65% </div> <div class="progress col "> <div class="determinate orange" style="width:65%">   </div> </div></a><a href="#!" class="collection-item" id="Malty"><h5 class="orange-text text-darken-2"> Malty</h5> <div class="right">15% </div> <div class="progress col "> <div class="determinate orange" style="width:15%">   </div> </div></a><a href="#!" class="collection-item" id="Smooth"><h5 class="orange-text text-darken-2"> Smooth</h5> <div class="right">15% </div> <div class="progress col "> <div class="determinate orange" style="width:15%">   </div> </div></a><a href="#!" class="collection-item" id="Dry"><h5 class="orange-text text-darken-2"> Dry</h5> <div class="right">5% </div> <div class="progress col "> <div class="determinate orange" style="width:5%">   </div> </div></a></div><div class="center-align" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0;"> <a id="redCircle" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a></div>




    <!-- Modal Structure For loading beer-->
    <div style="z-index: 1003; display: none; opacity: 0; transform: scaleX(0.7); top: 0px;" id="modal1" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content center">
            <div>
                <span class="card-title">Loading Taste Tags</span>
            </div>
            <div id="load" class="preloader-wrapper big active ">
                <div class="spinner-layer spinner-yellow-only">
                    <div class="circle-clipper left">
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gap-patch">
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="circle-clipper right">
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div style="left: 0px;" class="drag-target"></div><div class="hiddendiv common"></div></body></html>
```

My css I am using can be found here:

http://pastebin.com/bHW6Fzp3

Comment: make a fiddle please..

Comment: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ftu5rqg/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is the fix you are looking for, your container needs to have a width greater than the width of the button, and from there you can add margin: 0 auto;

As noted above, you should create a fiddle or similar first to demonstrate your problem.

```
.center-align {
    width: 100%;
}

.btn-floating.btn-large {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ftu5rqg/3/

I didn't notice the centering class that was already in there - all you really need is a width on the parent container, which in this example is .center-align.

Comment: I tried adding this inline and now myb utton is no longer floating but it is centered:

html += "<div style = \"width: 100%;\"class=\"center-align\" style=\"position: fixed; bottom: 0;\"> <a style = \"margin: 0 auto;\" id = \"redCircle\"  class=\"btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red\"><i class=\"material-icons\">add</i></a></div>";
            }

Comment: See above, I updated your fiddle in my answer - hope this helps.